# if i delete css property it should also be deleted from computed properties but its not?

Tags: jquery, css

```
.myProcessItem{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**my code workflow**: above is my simple class. I animate min-heigh and height properties through Jquery. then i delete only height property through Jquery.

Before adding these two properties, computed css has none of them
but when i delete only height property it got deleted from `element.style{}` class but computed css still contains height property. why is this so. It should be deleted from computed style also????

Tested through `chrome developer tools`

EDIT:

**myObjective**: my objective is to achieve scalable accordion

thats how i initialize in document.ready

```
  $(".myProcessItem").css("height","0px");
  $(".myProcessItem").css("min-height","40px");
```

then in onclick event

```
    var conHeight=$("#"+this.id+"Item").children().height();
    $(".myProcessItem").animate({"min-height":"0px"},200);  //i.e. minimize all other windows
    $("#"+this.id+"Item").animate({                         //open window that is clicked
        "min-height":conHeight

    },200,function(){
         $(".myProcessItem").css("height","");   //get rid of height to make it scalable
    });
```

in above code i just want my div to left only with min-height property and get rid of height property.

thing are working fine i.e maximize and minimize  but scalable thing is not working i.e auto adjust height.

EDIT:

What i did just right now is i added this statement `$(".myProcessItem").css("min-height","");`

```
 $(".myProcessItem").animate({"min-height":"0px"},200);  //i.e. minimize all other windows
 $("#"+this.id+"Item").animate({                         //open window that is clicked
    "min-height":conHeight

 },200,function(){
      $(".myProcessItem").css("height","");   //get rid of height to make it scalable
      $(".myProcessItem").css("min-height","");
 });
```

this is my computed css now

```
background-color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: block;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 18px;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 698px;
```

and accordion div become scalable though there is nothing special in computed css that should render such behaviour. Are these some bugs or my mistake.

Comment: this problem also consistent if i opt toggle class method i.e toggle with class having no height property

Comment: Can we see some of the JS code, since now it's not very understandable?

Comment: conHeight is a variable that contain height of its child div i.e accordian will maximize it self according to the height of child div. and i want additional feature i.e if i increase heigh of text element in my child my div should change its height dynamically. thats why i am trying to inject min-height property and get rid of height property.